# Modify Pandas dataframe to list year month and date

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to modify the data frame I am creating below:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY, YEARLY
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
import pandas

START_YR = 2010
END_YR = 2013

strt_date = datetime.date(START_YR, 1, 1)
end_date  = datetime.date(END_YR, 12, 31)

dt = rrule(DAILY, dtstart=strt_date, until=end_date)

serie_1 = pandas.Series(np.random.randn(dt.count()), \
        index = pandas.date_range(strt_date, end_date))
```

How can I create a dataframe with year month and date as separate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be significantly faster to just access the [datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) attributes:

```
df['date'] = df.index.date
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['month'] = df.index.month
```

compare the timings with the list comprehension method:

```
In [25]:

%%timeit
df['month'] = [ts.to_period('M') for ts in df.index]
df['year'] = [ts.to_period('Y') for ts in df.index]
df['month_int'] = [ts.month for ts in df.index]
1 loops, best of 3: 664 ms per loop
In [26]:

%%timeit
df['date'] = df.index.date
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['month'] = df.index.month

100 loops, best of 3: 5.96 ms per loop
```

So using the datetime properties is over 100X faster

Comment: Yes, properties are faster to execute, but Periods play nicer with the Pandas ecosystem (e.g. plotting, groupby, etc.).  Periods are stored as objects (thus taking more memory) and don't save easily to databases. Usage between the two approaches would depend upon preference and volume of data.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the series to a DataFrame and then add the new columns as Pandas periods.
If you just want the month as an integer, see the 'month_int' example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(serie_1)
df['month'] = [ts.to_period('M') for ts in df.index]
df['year'] = [ts.to_period('Y') for ts in df.index]
df['month_int'] = [ts.month for ts in df.index]

>>> df
Out[16]: 
                   0   month   year  month_int

2010-01-01  0.332370  2010-01  2010          1
2010-01-02 -0.036814  2010-01  2010          1
2010-01-03  1.751511  2010-01  2010          1
...              ...      ...   ...        ...
2013-12-29  0.345707  2013-12  2013         12
2013-12-30 -0.395924  2013-12  2013         12
2013-12-31 -0.614565  2013-12  2013         12
```